# Django + Channels: message interrupted by posting

Tags: django, post, django-channels

I am coding a page that contains a form to create a game (several field) and just below a list of all the created games.

When I post the new game, I would like the list of games to refresh for all the connected users of the page.

My consumer.py:

```
    def receive(self, text_data):
        games = serialize_games()

        # Send new game info to Lobby
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)( 'Lobby', { 'type': 'message_to_lobby', 'message': games, })

    def message_to_lobby(self, event):
        print('messages sent to lobby')
        message = event['message']
        self.send(text_data = message)
```

In my template I have a jquery portion of code that sends message to the websocket just prior the post is submitted:

```
$("#create_game_form").submit(function(e) { alert('sent');LobbySocket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'message': 'reload' }));});
```

During the posting, the receive function is well called, whereas the message handler (message_to_lobby) is not, since the rendering in the view section disconnect the websocket before...

Would it help to use async functions instead (I don't really see why...)? Or maybe Django + Channels are not meant to make POST and channels work together?

Otherwise, I may have the possibility to ask for the consumer to send an update signal to group users very 2sec or something like this, but I don"t find it very elegant.

Comment: Are you talking about submitting a POST request/form on the front-end and this interrupting the websocket?

Comment: I don't really know what happens btw those 2 options: 1) the message handler is not reached at all 2) the POST request interrupts the websocket prior to message handler can do anything

Comment: The POST request loads a different page and closes the websocket. If you want the websocket to stay connected then look into posting the form via AJAX or your websocket and calling `formSubmitEvent.preventDefault()` on the form submit event to stop the page load

Comment: Is it not possible to send the signals to all socket group prior to reload the page?